# Pages quitting overnight, then not restoring pages to the right windows when you restart it

Tags: pages

**This has been fixed in subsequent upgrades**

My favourite HTML editor no longer works with Ventura, so I needed a new tool to maintain my todo list (which I obviously use daily!) and settled on Pages. Unfortunately, Pages keeps quitting. It wouldn't be a big issue, except when you restart it, it throws all its windows on one desktop, rather than restoring them to other desktops, and I do have other ongoing actual writing projects with Pages pages up, each on their own desktops.

I have no idea whether this is new behaviour or even some kind of "feature", because TBH I don't look at those other desktops/projects that frequently so might have been attributing previous problems to just reboots of the laptop. But seriously, why doesn't all Apple software restore its pages to the right (previous) desktop anyway?

Comment: Spaces was never designed to be able to spread one app across multiple Spaces. What you're seeing is 'as intended'. [Not the crash, of course, which is probably what you should be investigating.]

Comment: Funnily enough, Chrome and Terminal and Finder do fine, but the behaviour in Preview & Pages are broken whatever you say about the intended design. There's just no way anyone ever wants to have previously distributed windows gathered together on one page after a reboot or program crash. Any design that expects that needs to be corrected.

Comment: Chrome & Terminal behave in the same way here, they gather windows on relaunch. It's not that the behaviour is disappointing, it's that it was never intended to work that way at all. Apple never foresaw it & Spaces itself has had no improvements since fullscreen was first added, with Mission Control. They just let it slide.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have found the settings to make most of my apps work the way I expect with Spaces. Chrome does the right thing now though it didn't used to, terminals have done the right thing for as long as I can remember, also finder windows.

Comment: By the way, I had to get up at 2am for a conference "in" Seoul, and Pages hasn't quit today, so it may be something about quitting after 8-10 hours of inactivity or similar.